# How do I associate the correct icon for my login?

Tags: unity, 11.10, icons

After upgrading to 11.10 from 11.04, the Unity launcher shows a question mark icon for libreoffice-calc.

If I log in using Unity2D or log into the guest account (2D or 3D), the correct icon appears.

How do I associate the correct icon for my login?

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

Save the file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LibreOffice_3.3.1_Calc_Icon.png

Later edit your `~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop`.

Find line with:

```
Icon=libreoffice-calc
```

And change it to your save file into:

```
Icon=*path-you-have-saved-it*
```

### Option 2

Locate file icon in your system using search option. In my case it is like:

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/256/libreoffice-oasis-spreadsheet.svg
```

so your line should look like:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/256/libreoffice-oasis-spreadsheet.svg
```

Comment: The second option you gave works great, I think it should be the first/only option.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it (right click > de-check "keep in launcher") then launch Calc from dash, and again right click > keep in launcher.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately, it does not solve the problem. I also removed the application using the software center and re-installed, and that did not work either.

Comment: Problem solved. I opened up the Main Menu app and set the icon there.